# How to retrieve the schema (type and columns) from a sql table and enforce them on a table in a synapse notebook?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dataframe, azure, pyspark

I have a few tables in a sql database. All these tables are empty but have the correct schema. Now I have corresponding tables in an Azure data lake with data but wrong schema.

I want to create a table combining the data of the data lake tables with the schema of the sql database tables.

What I try to do:

I have a synapse notebook with pyspark.

- I load in the schema of a sql table.
- I extract the matching table from the data lake
- I try to enforce the schema of the sql table on the table I get from the data lake
- I write the data to the sql database

In code:

```
container = "..."
storage_account = "..."
ls_name = "..."
adls_path = f"abfs://{container}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/test_table.parquet"
#set variable to be used to connect the database
SERVER = ...
DATABASE= ...
USERNAME= ...
PASSWORD= ...

#read table data for sql database
sqldf = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://{SERVER};databaseName={DATABASE}") \
    .option("dbtable", 'test_table') \
    .option("user", USERNAME) \
    .option("password", PASSWORD) \
    .load()

# Read in data lake table
pandasdf = pd.read_parquet(adls_path, storage_options = {'linked_service' : ls_name})
pandasdf = pandasdf[sqldf.columns] # to make the columns match
sparkdf = spark.createDataFrame(pandasdf)

# Create spark dataframe with correct data and correct schema
final = spark.createDataFrame(sparkdf.collect(), sqldf.schema, verifySchema=True)

#Write table data into a spark dataframe
final.write.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://{SERVER};databaseName={DATABASE}") \
    .option("dbtable", 'test_table1') \
    .option("user", USERNAME) \
    .option("password", PASSWORD) \
    .save()
```

The table 'test_table1' is indeed created. But when I look in the sql database and I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'test_table1'
```

I see the following:
[image]

And when I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'test_table'
```

I get this result:

[image]

Everything looks the same but the 'CHARACTER_MAXIMU_LENGTH' and the 'CHARACTER_OCET_LENGTH' are way off. -1 vs some set number. (-1 I think indicates the maximum number possible)

So this means the schema's aren't exactly the same. I need the schema's of 'test_table1' to be the same as 'test_table'.

How can I do this?

(

- I have multiple tables with a lot of columns and I don't want to specify for all those tables individually what the schema characteristics should be.
- In some of those tables the types from the data lake table are of doubletype and should be int or float in sql. This often raises the error that it can't convert the columns. But If I do it manually by casting the type it works
  )

Comment: Add the `sqldf.schema` in the question which will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code and It should give you the Similar Results.

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS "SchemaName",
       TABLE_NAME AS "ObjectName",
       ORDINAL_POSITION AS "ColOrd",
       COLUMN_NAME AS "ColumnName",
       DOMAIN_NAME AS "UserDataType",
       DATA_TYPE AS "SystemDataType",
       CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('xml', 'hierarchyid', 'geography', 'sql_variant', 'image', 'text', 'ntext') THEN NULL ELSE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH END AS "Length",
       CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN NUMERIC_PRECISION ELSE NULL END AS "Precision",
       CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN NUMERIC_SCALE ELSE NULL END AS "Scale",
       DATA_TYPE + CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN CONCAT('(',NUMERIC_PRECISION,',',NUMERIC_SCALE,')')
                        WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'binary', 'varbinary') THEN CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN '(max)' ELSE CONCAT('(',CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,')') END
                    ELSE '' END AS "ConfiguredDataType",
       CASE IS_NULLABLE WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "isNull",
       SUBSTRING(COLUMN_DEFAULT, 2, LEN(COLUMN_DEFAULT)-2) AS "DefaultValue"
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'categories'
```

Query to get the same results from sys.columns

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(O.schema_id) AS "SchemaName",
       OBJECT_NAME(O.object_id) AS "ObjectName",
       CASE WHEN O.type = 'U' THEN 'UserTable' WHEN O.type = 'V' THEN 'View' WHEN O.type = 'TF' THEN 'TableValuedFn' ELSE '' END AS "ObjectType",
       C.column_id AS "ColID",
       COLUMNPROPERTY(C.object_id, C.name, 'ordinal') AS "ColOrd",
       C.name AS "ColumnName",
       CASE WHEN C.user_type_id <> C.system_type_id THEN TYPE_NAME(C.user_type_id) ELSE '' END AS "UserDataType",
       ISNULL(TYPE_NAME(C.system_type_id), TYPE_NAME(C.user_type_id)) AS "SystemDataType",
       ISNULL(CAST(COLUMNPROPERTY(C.object_id, C.name, 'charmaxlen') AS NVARCHAR(10)), '') AS "Length",
       CASE WHEN TYPE_NAME(C.system_type_id) IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN CAST(C.precision AS NVARCHAR(4)) ELSE '' END AS "Precision",
       CASE WHEN TYPE_NAME(C.system_type_id) IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN CAST(C.scale AS NVARCHAR(4)) ELSE '' END AS "Scale",
       ISNULL(TYPE_NAME(C.system_type_id), TYPE_NAME(C.user_type_id))
            + CASE
                 WHEN TYPE_NAME(C.system_type_id) IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN '(' + CAST(C.precision AS VARCHAR(4)) + ', ' + CAST(C.scale AS VARCHAR(4)) + ')'
                 WHEN C.max_length = -1 AND TYPE_NAME(C.system_type_id) NOT IN ('xml') THEN '(max)'
                 WHEN ISNULL(TYPE_NAME(C.system_type_id), TYPE_NAME(C.user_type_id)) IN ('xml', 'hierarchyid', 'geography', 'sql_variant', 'image', 'text', 'ntext') THEN ''
                 ELSE ISNULL('('+CAST(COLUMNPROPERTY(C.object_id, C.name, 'charmaxlen') AS NVARCHAR(10))+')', '')
              END AS "ConfiguredSystemType",
       ISNULL(C.is_nullable, 0) AS "isNull",
       ISNULL(SUBSTRING(OBJECT_DEFINITION(C.default_object_id), 2, LEN(OBJECT_DEFINITION(C.default_object_id)) - 2), '') AS "DefaultValue",
       C.is_identity AS "isIdentity",
       C.is_computed AS "isComputed"
FROM sys.columns AS C
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS O ON O.object_id = C.object_id
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(O.schema_id) = 'dbo' AND O.name = 'categories'
```

Comment: This shows the same discrepancy (-1 vs some set number) that I already showed in the question.

Comment: The "-1" represents (MAX) except for XML

Comment: Seems like the *real* question, @Herwini , is why have you defined all your columns as a value that is likely to contain *more* than **8,000 bytes** (4,000 characters for an `nvarchar`)?

Comment: As an aside, however, you should really be using the `sys` objects, @ChandraSaiKarthik, rather than the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects; the latter is for compatibility and therefore lacks some (a lot) of information and (at least historically) was documented to sometimes be incorrect.

Comment: Why do u consider "CHARACTER_OCET_LENGTH" which represents the data storage.?
@ThomA, I can refer sys.columns and sys.types to get the actual data.
i thought it would cause more confusion for analysing.
To get the System Datatype and User Defined Data Types it is more of joins which makes bit weird.
so i used information_schema.columns for DOMAIN_NAME AS "UserDataType", DATA_TYPE AS "SystemDataType"

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't say that using the specific SQL Server objects for this information is "weird". ;)

Comment: @ThomA, I added the Query that brings the data from sys.columns.
Weird is something i referred when the table contains the columns like 'hierarchyid', 'geography', 'sql_variant'.